# Weird VB.net showing texts to other forms behavior

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi guys i have this program that I want to show the text of my form1 to my form3 in which the form2 has the button to execute the command there were no errors in the debug but when I click the button in my form2 the data that I want on my form3 from my form1 were not there. Please help me guys thanks in advance.

Form1 codes:

```
 Public Class Form1
Private frm2 As Form2
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    If frm2 Is Nothing Then
        frm2 = New Form2
        AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Me.Form2HasBeenClosed

        Dim Label21 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label21.Text = TextBox1.Text
        frm2.Label21.ForeColor = Color.Black
     End If

    If frm2 IsNot Nothing Then
        frm2.Show(Me) 'Show Second Form  
        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
```

Form2 codes:

```
Public Class Form2
Private frm1 As New Form1
Private frm3 As Form3
Public lbl As New Label
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim Label21 As Label = New Label
    Dim Textbox1 As TextBox = New TextBox
    frm3.Label21.Text = frm1.TextBox1.Text

        Form3.Show()


End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the reference of the Form1 instance to the instance of Form2 called frm2.
When, inside the Form2 class code you try to show Form3 you should use that reference to pass the values present in the initial instance of Form1. Instead your code builds a new instance of Form1 (`Form1 frm = new Form1`) and tries to get the values from this instance. Of course, being a new instance of Form1, the `frm1` variable doesn't contain any of the values present in the original instance.

```
Public Class Form2
    Private frm1 As Form1   ' remove the new here because it creates a new instance of Form1'
    Private frm3 As Form3
    Public lbl As New Label ' not needed?'

    ' add a constructor that receives the instance of the caller'
    Public Sub New(callerInstance as Form1)

        ' Call required if you add your constructor manually'
        InitializeComponent()

        ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor'
        frm1 = callerInstance
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

       ' Dim Label21 As Label = New Label          ' this label is not needed'
       ' Dim Textbox1 As TextBox = New TextBox     ' this  textbox is not needed'

       ' Create a new instance of Form3, do not use the automatic Form3 instance
       ' automatically created by VB.NET 
       frm3 = new Form3()

       ' now you are referring to the caller instance of Form1 '
       ' where there is the textbox filled with your text '
       frm3.Label21.Text = frm1.TextBox1.Text
       frm3.Show()

     End Sub
End Class
```

Then you change the code in Fomr1 class that builds the Form2 instance in this way

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(...........)

    If frm2 Is Nothing Then
        frm2 = New Form2(Me)
        .....
```

This change calls the constructor defined in the class code of Form2 with the current instance of Form1 (Me) and it is this instance that contains the textbox value that you need to pass to frm3 later.

I don't want to patronize here but it seems that you have a bit of confusion about classes and instances of a class. You need to understand this point very well because is one of the basic pillars of Object Oriented Programming. (Well VB with its automatic creation of Form objects doesn't help here)

A very basic introduction here: [Classes and Objects](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chp1.htm)

Comment: Sir thanks for all your help..I have a question Private Sub New(callerInstance as Form1) commits an error on the debug I tried to figure it out but I can't im just new in programming please help me thanks the error is Warning 2 'Private Sub New(callerInstance As Form1)' in designer-generated type 'WindowsApplication1.Form2' should call InitializeComponent method.

Comment: sir sorry but this guide is not clear please help me on how to incorporate the initialize component through my code thanks a lot sir many many thanks

Comment: Hi sir steve yes it fixes the problem but another problem came up Error 1 'WindowsApplication1.Form2.Private Sub New(callerInstance As Form1)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'. it made an error on my form1

Comment: Hi sir it created another error Error 1 Argument not specified for parameter 'callerInstance' of 'Public Sub New(callerInstance As Form1)'.

Comment: you saved my life sir :) thank you many thanks i really appreciate it :) MANY THANKS AGAIN SIR!! I am really happy that this one is solved already thanks thanks thanks thank you :)

Comment: Thank to you, I have revised the answer with the details emerged in these comments. Now it should be fine also for future passers by